# How to include ThrowTheSwitch/Unity in a C project?

Tags: c, git, dependencies, unity-test-framework

I would like to use ThrowTheSwitch Unity for my unit tests in several projects so I have this generic structure:

```
.
├── README.md
├── Makefile
├── src
│   ├── ...
│   └── main.c
└── test
    ├── vendor
    │   ├── unity.c
    │   └── unity.h
    └── test_main.c
```

To include unity I could use different approach:

1. Git Submodules

   - **pros**: git only, one single source of truth
   - **cons**: get all the unity repository while only 3 files are required
2. Git Submodules with sparse checkout

   - **pros**: only get what I need
   - **cons**: need some hack to enable the sparse-checkout
3. Git Subtree

   - **pros**: safe if no internet available
   - **cons**: keep local copies of unity in the history
4. Wget from a release

   - **pros**: very simple, very effective
   - **cons**: dependency on `wget` and `tar` and internet (no local cache)
5. Local copy of unity

   - **pros**: most simple solution, effective
   - **cons**: not SSOT, all similar projects will have their local copy of unity, lost track of which unity version is synced.

It seems none of the above method is perfect and I don't know which one to choose. The best solution would be to have a simple package manager with a `package.json` file that list my dependencies and their versions.

Is there any other/better solution?